# Page div that has scroll bars, need to show entire div contents on print

Tags: html, css, browser, printing, media-queries

I have a div and table on my page:

```
<div id="tablediv">
    <table id="table">
         <tr><th>headers</th></tr>
         <tr><td>contents</td></tr>
    </table>
<div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#tablediv {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

So that no matter the height the table, the div will scroll it, the page does not scroll.

I want to have the print view to show then entire length of the table, say over multiple pages. But it only shows what it can fit on the first page, no other pages for the rest of the div/table rows.

How can I do this with `@media print` CSS?

Comment: have you tried this? @media print{ .tablediv{ height:100%;overflow:visible;} }

Comment: Still not workey

Answer (score 0):

Try to overwrite the height in a media query.  The query needs to come second so it overwrites the original declaration.

```
#tablediv {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}

@media print { 
    #tablediv {
        max-height: auto;
        height: auto;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```